# Unable to send string from one activity to another (third activity) in Android Studio using Kotlin

Tags: android, string, kotlin, android-intent, intentservice

So I have three activities for my app. I am taking the username from the user(on Main Screen) and I want to show it to the last screen (Result Screen). I have tried using string constants and then sending the string value using Intent from one activity to the second and to the third one. But I am not able to see the name on the Result Screen. What is that I am doing wrong ?

I am following all the rules and the app is working fine without errors but the username is not been shown to the screen.

In Constants.kt

```
 const val USER_NAME: String = "user_name"
```

In MainActivity.kt

```
val nameEditText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name_edit_text)  
val name = nameEditText.text.toString()  
val Intent = Intent(this, QuizQuestionActivity::class.java)  
intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_NAME, name)  
startActivity(intent)
```

In QuizQuestionActivity.kt

```
private var mUsername: String? = null 
mUsername = intent.getStringExtra(CONSTANTS.USER_NAME) 
val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)  
intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_NAME, mUsername)  
startActivity(intent)
```

In ResultActivity.kt

```
val username = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.USER_NAME)  
tv_name.text = username
```

This is the whole code I am trying to execute. Anybody please help!!

Comment: Before sending the value to ResultActivity, you need to assign mUsername to the value that you got from the MainActivity intent right? 

mUsername = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.USER_NAME)

Comment: @pepperlove , Yes sorry, I am actually doing it in the code, I forget to paste that here. But it's still not working

Comment: Are you able to get the value in QuizQuestionActivity?

Comment: @pepperlove I am not sure about that, because I am just passing it through that activity without actually showing it on a view. Should i check it with Log statement ?

Comment: can this be because I am using TextInputLayout instead of an EditText in xml ?

Answer (score 2):

I have two Observations in your code snippet

1)Do you have two Constant files?

1. Constant.kt
2. CONSTANT.kt

As in your QuizQuestionActivity, there is a line

```
mUsername = intent.getStringExtra(CONSTANTS.USER_NAME)
```

No matter the file that you refer to, the USER_NAME field string values should be the same.

2)Another thing in MainActivity

```
val Intent = Intent(this, QuizQuestionActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_NAME, name)  
startActivity(intent)
```

Here variable that you use is "Intent"

```
val Intent = Intent(this, QuizQuestionActivity::class.java)
```

and you pass "intent" for starting activity

```
intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_NAME, name)  
startActivity(intent)
```

**Try this**

In MainActivity:

```
val nameEditText = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.name_edit_text)
val name = nameEditText.text.toString()
val intent = Intent(this, QuizQuestionActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_NAME, name)
startActivity(intent)
```

In QuizQuestionActivity:-

```
var mUsername: String? = null
mUsername = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.USER_NAME)
val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_NAME, mUsername)
startActivity(intent)
```

In ResultActivity:-

```
val username = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.USER_NAME)
tv_name.text = username
```

Comment: Yes you were right. There was a an issue with intent/Intent, but unfortunately solving that doesn't solved the main issue. Name is still not visible on the Result Screen.
Also using findViewById<TextInputEditText> instead of <EditText> is making the app crash.